# PDFMerger.php - Orientation not working?

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm trying to use PDFMerger.php (https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger) to set up a script which will merge PDF's and output a download.

So far, everything is working - However, the orientation doesn't seem to be working, my eBook is in Landscape mode, but PDFMerger keeps outputting the download in Portrait mode, thus cutting off half of my page.

The code I'm using to test is:

```
<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger; // or use $pdf = new \PDFMerger; for Laravel


$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/ebook.pdf', '1, 3, 7', 'L');
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/ebook.pdf', 'all', 'L');


$pdf->merge('file', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'all' ,'L'); // generate the file

$pdf->merge('download', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf', 'all', 'L'); // force download 
?>
```

The output of which can be seen here: http://crunch.alunfisher.co.uk/uniclearing/PDF/pdf.php

If anyone could offer any advice, or an alternative solution - It'd be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with FPDF and FPDI, as opposed to PDFMerger or the code itself, updating both now outputs my PDF at the correct orientation.

Thanks anyway!